# Are two planes in $\Bbb R^4$ parallel or not?

Tags: vectors

I have two planes in $\Bbb R^4$ and I am trying to determine if they are parallel or not. They are of the form $\mathcal P = (0, 1, 1, 0) + \Bbb R(1, 3, 4, 2) + \Bbb R(3, 1, 2, 4)$ AND $\mathcal Q = (4, 2, 1, 0) + \Bbb R(1, 3, 6, 6) + \Bbb R(6, 2, 2, 8)$ as an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. What did you try? Where are you stuck? What is your definition of two parallel planes?

Comment: Hi Stephane I set the 4 vectors as a 4x4 matrix and used Gaussian elimination to find a unique solution meaning (I think) that the vectors are linearly independent and hence not parallel.